# Whats wrong with MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete rows from a table that spit out from a join:

```
  DELETE FROM t1 WHERE company_name IN 
    (SELECT company_name FROM t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN t2
        ON t2.company_name = t1.company_name
        WHERE t2.name IS null)

Column 'company_name' in field list is ambiguous
```

Getting this ambiguous error while trying to make this query? Any suggestions?

Comment: `SELECT company_name`  Which one?  Both `t1` and `t2` have a `company_name` field.

Comment: Lol, it says FROM t1 right there, mysql can't understand that?

Comment: That's not what `FROM` means.  When you `JOIN` you are adding another table, so it doesn't know which.  You need to be specific: `SELECT t1.company_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't like it when you try to `UPDATE`/`DELETE` a table and `SELECT` from the same table in the same query.

You can solve this with multi-table `DELETE` syntax:

```
DELETE t1 FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 USING (company_name)
WHERE t2.name IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
   DELETE FROM t1 WHERE company_name IN ( select * from (SELECT t1.company_name FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.company_name = t1.company_name WHERE t2.name IS null) t )
```

Comment: Error: You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

As the error message tells the column name `company_name` is not unique. Depending on your needs I believe this may solve your problem assuming you're trying to delete entries in `t1` which doesn't have a corresponding row in `t2` or have one but with `name` is null:

```
DELETE FROM
    t1
WHERE
    company_name NOT IN (
        SELECT
            t2.company_name
        FROM
            t2
        WHERE
            t2.name IS NOT NULL
    )
```

Comment: You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Why not? I'm pretty sure this works on most DBMS. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: Ok, I changed the query with a new approach which I guess matches your intention.